# Why does code in with-temp-buffer complain about void variable when "parent" buffer has a local variable of the same name I've bound?

Tags: dynamic, emacs, lisp, elisp

I just spent ages figuring out what was wrong with my code. It worked just fine in ert unit tests, but failed when I ran it in a larger context. Here is an example of a code which worked:

```
(defun func (my-var)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (message my-var)))

(func "z")
```

This prints z as expected. Now I was writing a major mode which had some buffer-local variables. One of these was my-var. This code demonstrates my issue:

```
(make-local-variable 'my-var)
(setq my-var "y")

(defun func (my-var)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (message my-var)))

(func "z")
```

The output? There is none, only this error message:

```
eval-buffer: Symbol's value as variable is void: my-var
```

In this example it is easy to see that the buffer-local variable interferes somehow with the dynamically bound my-var. It wasn't so easy when I had multiple screens worth of code though :-)

So my question is what is really going on here? It's obvious that the temp-buffer somehow inherits a variable from the "parent" buffer, but why does it have a void value? I would understand if it would get the value "y" somehow, but this behavior feels like a bug to me.

PS. I'm running the latest Aquamacs

Answer (score 3):

A couple of things.

First, your code doesn't work as-is.  You should try this in a new invocation of Emacs.  Once you do, you'll see that you need to pass `make-local-variable` a symbol, like so:

```
(make-local-variable 'my-var)
```

Note the ```.

Second, you've defined a buffer-local variable to have the same name as the parameter to `func`, so any answer needs to distinguish between the two.

So, here's my cleaned up version of your example:

```
(make-local-variable 'my-var)
(setq my-var "y")

(defun func (my-param)
  (with-temp-buffer
(message my-param)))

(func "z")
```

And this works just fine.

Which leads me to believe that the error you're seeing is from the call to `make-local-variable` without the quote in front of `my-var`.

Original answer provided below, though it doesn't address the problem:

---

Check out the documentation for [`make-local-variable`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Locals.html).  The doc string is:

> make-local-variable is an interactive built-in function in `C source
>   code'.
>
> (make-local-variable VARIABLE)
>
> Make VARIABLE have a separate value in the current buffer. Other
>   buffers will continue to share a common default value. (The
>   buffer-local value of VARIABLE starts out as the same value VARIABLE
>   previously had.  If VARIABLE was void, it remains void.) Return
>   VARIABLE.

The key part for you is the last sentence.  `If the variable was void, it remains void.`

This means that if it was not already defined globally, it is still not defined globally.  In other words, it only has a binding in the buffers in which it has been explicitly set.

If you want it to have a global value, use `setq-default` like so:

```
(setq-default my-var "some-default-value")
```

Comment: But I still don't understand why it is void. I create it with: (make-local-variable my-var) and then I set value "y" to it:
(setq my-var "y"). So by the time I call the function and with-temp-buffer macro within the value should not be void. What am I missing?

Comment: "In other words, it only has a binding in the buffers in which it has been explicitly set." <- I didn't set it explicitly in the temp-buffer created within the macro with-temp-buffer. The buffer somehow inherited the variable but not it's value. Also, I don't want to create a global variable if I can avoid that. I can live with this feature just fine, I just have to remember to name the variables carefully. I'd just like to know why this happens.

Comment: Actually, there are a couple of things going on here in your code, I'll update my answer.

Comment: The missing apostrophe was a typo, thanks. I added it there now. My "real" code did have the apostrophe. So if you now evaluate the code you should see the same error message. Your cleaned up version with different variable names works, of course. And that's my workaround/solution to this problem now. But still: I'd like to know exactly why the temporary buffer created with with-temp-buffer macro gives me a void-value variable when I have a local variable in the "main" buffer with a non-void value. Is it a bug or some feature which I don't understand?

Comment: @auramo Wow.  Must investigate, this is very interesting.  And, it only happens when you've defined the variable with `make-local-variable`.  Seems like a bug in the variable lookup code to me. (Emacs 23.2).

Comment: @auramo I filed a bug against Emacs.  http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=10604

Comment: Immediately got a wontfix tag :-)

Comment: Yah, I saw that and was going to update the answer.  There's a reason for it... would be interesting to explore the downsides to "fixing" it.